# Angular 7 pwa/ SwPush - push notifications not working

Tags: angular, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to make push notifications work in Angular 7 using @angular/pwa [link](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)  and using SwPush. I am not able to get actual push notifications.
I am currently working on localhost (by running http-server after doing an ng-build) and my api server is located in cloud.
I was able to enable the subscription using swPush.requestSubscription and the subscription is registered successfully on the server.
In Chrome, all the api calls get blocked from the service worker itself (failed : from service Worker) while in Firefox, there is no error but the push message does not appear.

I have added the relevant code snippets below. Since there are no specific errors reported, I am not able to proceed further.

Please advise on how to make this work and show notifications.

```
app.module.ts

import {PushNotificationService} from 'core';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,

],
imports: [

    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: true })
],
providers: [
    PushNotificationService,
],
exports: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
 export class AppModule {
  }


   app.component.ts
export class AppComponent  {

constructor(private pushNotification :PushNotificationService,
private swPush : SwPush){
this.swPush.messages.subscribe(notification => {
          const notificationData: any = notification;
     const options = {
      body: notificationData.message,
      badgeUrl: notificationData.badgeUrl,
      icon: notificationData.iconUrl
    };
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(reg => {
      console.log('showed notification');
      reg.showNotification(notificationData.title, options).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      }, err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    });
  });

}
     isSupported() {
      return this.pushNotification.isSupported;
   }

  isSubscribed() {
  console.log(' ****** profile component' + this.swPush.isEnabled);
  return this.swPush.isEnabled;
}

 enablePushMessages() {
  console.log('Enable called'); 
  this.pushNotification.subscribeToPush();

}

 disablePushMessages(){
  // code for unsubsribe
  }
}
```

push.notification.service

```
 export class PushNotificationService {
 public isSupported = true;
 public isSubscribed = false;
 private swRegistration: any = null;
  private userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private swPush: SwPush) {
   if ((this.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') > -1) || 
   (this.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) || (this.userAgent.indexOf('.Net') 
    > -1)) {
      this.isSupported = false;
    }
}

subscribeToPush() {
// Requesting messaging service to subscribe current client (browser)
  let publickey = 'xchbjhbidcidd'
   this.swPush.requestSubscription({
    serverPublicKey: publickey
   }).then(pushSubscription => {
     console.log('request push subscription ', pushSubscription);
     this.createSubscriptionOnServer(pushSubscription);
      })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

 createSubscriptionOnServer(subscription) {
  let urlName = 'api/user/notificationSubscription';
  let params;
  params = {
  endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
   };
this.http.put<any>(urlName, params, httpOptions).pipe(
  tap((res) => {
    if (res.data) {
      if (res.data.success) {
        alert('Success')
      } else {
        alert('error')
      }
    }
  }));
 }
 }
```

Comment: are you having https?. PWA won't work with the dev build.

Comment: can you reproduce the error with stackblitz(https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: @DharanG I am testing it in local environment ,not in dev .

Answer (score 8):

You need to install Angular CLI, PWA for service worker, webpush for generating VAPID keys and http-server for running a mock server. You can do it by running:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli --save
ng add @angular/pwa --save
npm i webpush --save
npm i http-server -g --save
```

Now you need to generate VAPID key pair using webpush for using it in front end and backend

```
web-push generate-vapid-keys --json
```

Save the generated pair somewhere. Use the below code in the app.component.ts to request a subscription from the user

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(swPush: SwPush) {
if (swPush.isEnabled) {
  swPush.requestSubscription({
      serverPublicKey: VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
    })
    .then(subscription => {
      // send subscription to the server
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
  }
}
```

VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY is the public key you got earlier.

Add this on your Angular project inside the node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received. event:%s', event);
            event.notification.close();
            if (clients.openWindow && event.notification.data.url) {
                event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
            }
        });
```

You can enter the above code where you find the below line inside the file> it would be in line number 1893.

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => ..
```

And you have to build the dist again for this to work.
Now use

```
ng build --prod
```

to generate the dist and serve it using

```
http-server ./dist/YOUR_DIST_FOLDER_NAME -p 9999
```

And in backend file your could should be something like this.

```
const express = require('express');
const webpush = require('web-push');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const PUBLIC_VAPID = 'PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY';
const PRIVATE_VAPID = 'PRIVATE_VAPID_KEY';

const fakeDatabase = [];

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

webpush.setVapidDetails('mailto:you@domain.com', PUBLIC_VAPID, PRIVATE_VAPID);

app.post('/subscription', (req, res) => {
       const subscription = req.body;
      fakeDatabase.push(subscription);
    });

app.post('/sendNotification', (req, res) => {
  const notificationPayload = {
    {"notification":
       { 
        "body":"This is a message.",
        "title":"PUSH MESSAGE",
        "vibrate":300,100,400,100,400,100,400],
        "icon":"ICON_URL",
        "tag":"push demo",
        "requireInteraction":true,
        "renotify":true,
        "data":
          { "url":"https://google.com"}
       }
    }
  };

  const promises = [];
  fakeDatabase.forEach(subscription => {
    promises.push(webpush.sendNotification(subscription, 
JSON.stringify(notificationPayload)));
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => res.sendStatus(200));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Inside the url you can enter your url and on clicking notification your push notification will open the given link and focus it in the browser.

Comment: I have followed the same but I am not getting notification in Chrome(Version 72.0.3626.119) . In firefox its working

Comment: Can you try again by updating your Chrome? Run in the production mode and try again.

Comment: Lastly you can try updating your packages  'ng add @angular/pwa', 'npm i webpush' and 'npm i http-server -g' again. And rerun your project.

Answer (score 4):

for the service-worker to works you need to compile with --prod.
try to compile using ng build --prod

Comment: Service worker will not be activated just by running in prod mode. Website should run in https for the service-worker to operate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **Google Chrome notifications** was **disabled** on my **Windows** machine, in *Notifications & actions* settings.